# Determine ELO strength without playing in FIDE tournaments

Tags: rating, elo

I don't play club chess or tournaments, how can I determine my ELO strength? 
I often play on chess.com how well does it compare to the FIDE system? (I am aware that one cannot account for people cheating online)

Comment: Ratings from different systems cannot be directly compared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is going to sound tautological, but Elo is inherently a measure of how you do in tournaments. Your question is sort of like asking "I don't run, how can I determine how fast I can run a mile?" We could guess from how generally fit you look, but in reality you just have to go run a mile to find out.

There are correlations between various online ratings and a FIDE rating, but they're just correlations; the context of how you play online is very different from playing live (for one thing, online games are usually much faster).

I can tell you that the first time you play in a live tournament you will likely perform 100-200 points worse than you might expect from such a correlation, just because you're not used to the environment of a face-to-face tournament (moving real pieces, using a clock, writing down your moves, having your opponent right there in front of you, being distracted by other games). Luckily it does not take long to settle in.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get an accurate estimate of your Elo strength is to actually get an Elo rating.

If you accuracy isn't that important you could take [a test like this](http://www.elometer.net). There are surely others somewhere. For example in some books (unfortunately I only know [a non-English example](http://www.amazon.de/Lehr--%C3%9Cbungs--Testbuch-Schachkombinationen-Colditz/dp/3283003025/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8)).

Concerning the chess.com rating: In my experience your Elo should be a bit higher than your chess.com rating, but tournament games and internet blitz can be very different.

Comment: kein Problem, gut wenn man Deutsch kann ;-)

Comment: Hmm, jetzt wo ich mir Deinen Namen noch mal anschaue … ;-) Das Buch ist auf jeden Fall eine sehr gute Einführung in die Taktik und wenn ich mich richtig erinnere gibt es am Ende einen Test der einen irgendwo zwischen 0 und 2840 Elo einordnet.

Answer (score -1):

There was one psychologists site studying such things who had a sample test that would estimate your rating.  While you really need to play enough games OTB and get a real FIDE rating you could use that site to estimate your rating.

Alternatively you could play at some online sites and subtract a few hundred points to roughly estimate your FIDE rating.

NOTE that the rating depends a lot on the time control!